# Nginx Reverse Proxy do not load JS and CSS from other server

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, angular

I have two version of a WebApp, running on two different servers (prod and dev). Prod version is available on `exemple.com`, and dev version on `exemple.com/dev`. However, when I set the proxy to load dev version, only the index.html file is loaded, JS and CSS are not loaded.
If I check the request url in devtools, I see that `index.html` comes from `https://exemple.com/dev` while `main.bundle.js` comes from `https://exemple.com/`

Here is the `nginx.conf` for prod server

```
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        #listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /site/app;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, authorization' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
        }

        location /dev {
                proxy_pass http://10.10.38.18/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
```

And here for dev server:

```
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        #listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /site/webApp;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
                autoindex on;
        }
        location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, authorization' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
        }
```

Comment: Your backend should generate the correct URLs.

Comment: I can't see where the url is not correct. My app is made with Angular I only have static html, js and css files in my folders

Comment: Set the baseurl to `/dev/` https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is possible to configure nginx to rewrite URLs in the content before serving it using [`sub_filter`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) this puts heavy load on nginx which usually is completely unnecessary.

It is far better to configure the application to generate the correct URLs directly. For Angular this is the [`APP_BASE_HREF`](https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF) setting.